# Распаковка Zip файла в папку с именем как у архива

Tags: java, zip

Помогите доработать код. Распаковывает Zip на отлично, только мне нужно, чтобы он еще и распаковывал файлы в папку с таким именем как и имя архива.

```
private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
{       
 InputStream is;
 ZipInputStream zis;
 try 
 {
     is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
     zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
     ZipEntry ze;

     while((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
     {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;

         String filename = ze.getName();
         FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

         // reading and writing
         while((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
         {
             baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
             byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
             fout.write(bytes);             
             baos.reset();
         }

         fout.close();               
         zis.closeEntry();
     }

     zis.close();
 } 
 catch(IOException e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
 }

return true;
}
```

Comment: То есть вам непонятно как получить имя архива, без расширения, как создать папку с таким именем или как распаковать zip в нее?

Comment: Семен Семеныч! Так в чем проблема? Декомпозицию задачи сделайте и поиск в гугле.

1. Выделить из название архива - оно и так есть в переменной `filename`

2. Проверить существует ли соответствующая папка `path+filename`
Используйте `java.nio.file.Files` и `Files.exists(path)`

3. Если не существует - создаем папку
`new File("C:\\Directory1").mkdir();` из `java.io.File`

4. Переходим в созданную папку. Или доклеиваем ее название в переменную path.

5. Распаковываем. PROFIT.

Answer (score 3):

Вот цикл while переписал:

```
while((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;

                String filename = ze.getName();
                if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                    File directPath = new File(path + zipname.substring(0,zipname.length()-4) + "\\" + filename);
                    directPath.mkdirs();
                } else {
                    File directPath = new File(path + zipname.substring(0,zipname.length()-4) + "\\");
                    directPath.mkdir();
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + zipname.substring(0,zipname.length()-4) + "\\" + filename);

                    // reading and writing
                    while((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        fout.write(bytes);
                        baos.reset();
                    }

                    fout.close();
                    zis.closeEntry();
                }
            }
```

Comment: zipname.substring(0,zipname.length()-4) - без этого он будет пытаться писать в архив, но лучше брать до последней точки, через lastIndexOf.

Comment: @AlexTortov, не за что)